# vba - find numbers or strings in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to look for same values in two different workbooks.
when the cells contains strings, it works fine, but when I am trying to look just numbers, even though there is a matching cell with the same numbers, it doesn't work.

any ideas?

```
strSearch = "123" 'the number to look for
rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
```

Comment: For starters, it should be `Set rFound = ...`.

Comment: I deleted the Set, when I posted my question... as I mentioned, it works good with strings. the problam is when there is only numbers, not strings.

Comment: Perhaps, but if you are going to post code and then ask *Why doesn't this code work?* then you should be posting the actual code.

Comment: Are both values exactly the same or just formatted to look the same?  One might be 123.01 formatted to 0 decimal places, the other may not.  Not sure if I'm talking rubbish here - is searching for "123" (text string) different than searching for 123 (numeric)?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - Good point on the actual value sought; you can find **123** by looking for **"123"**.

Comment: ok Jeeped I understand. now, the problam is, that I can't know what is the type of the cell in the search files. I got a source file, some of it's cells contains strings and some numbers, and if the user wants to look by a cell with just a number value - then it doesn't work.
the variable strSearch - is actually contains: .Cells(i, 1).Value - something like that - a cell value.

Comment: As of my experiences one can not use `Range.Find` properly without knowing the format of the searched value. For example with `LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole` `123` will not be found if the cell value is `123` formatted as `123.00`. Then only `123.00` will be found. So `LookIn:=xlValues` means "how the value looks in the cell". With `LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole` `123` will be found if the cells value is `123`, even if formatted. So `LookIn:=xlFormulas` takes the cell's content `123` like the formula `=123`. But of course then it will not find `123` if the cell contains `=1230/10`.

Comment: @Axel Richter thank you - it is part of the problam! is there a wat to do something like: LookIn:=xlFormulas or LookIn:=xlValues ?

Comment: Do not use `.Find`. Loop over all cells (or better over the data array) and find the matching value with `If cellContent = searchedValue Then ... EndIf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as already mentioned in comments below OP post, `find` method is not applicable for searching of the values through the formula result (=123/10), so for such purposes you shall use looping through the range as in example below:

```
Sub test()
    Dim cl As Range, s$
    s = "123"
    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cl.Value = s Then Debug.Print cl.Address(0, 0)
    Next cl
End Sub
```

test:

[image]

also, if you need to find cell which is contains searching string then you can use something like this:

```
Option Compare Text
Sub test2()
    Dim cl As Range, s$
    s = "S"
    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cl.Value Like "*" & s & "*" Then Debug.Print cl.Address(0, 0)
    Next cl
End Sub
```

or:

```
Sub test3()
    Dim cl As Range, s$
    s = "123"
    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If InStr(1, cl.Value, s, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Debug.Print cl.Address(0, 0)
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below Code. But i think this will be slower if the data is huge.

```
strSearch = "123" 'the number to look for
  Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cell In wks.UsedRange

    srcstr = cell.Value


    If InStr(1, srcstr, strSearch, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        cell.Activate
        Exit Sub
    End If


Next
```